# Why does adding a \label at the beginning of a \parbox affect its layout?

Tags: vertical-alignment, parbox

I was surprised to notice that adding a `\label` at the beginning of a parbox changed the layout of its contents:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
A\parbox[t]{3em}{\tiny B\\C} (no label)

A\parbox[t]{3em}{\tiny \label{y}B\\C} (label before text)

A\parbox[t]{3em}{\tiny B\label{z}\\C} (label after text)
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

What is causing this, and what is the proper way to place a label within a parbox without affecting the layout of its contents?  Adding an `\mbox{}` before the `\label` does it… but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical versus horizontal mode.  Sounds like `\label` does not like being called in vertical mode.  By the way, `\mbox{}` also takes one out of vertical mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
A\parbox[t]{3em}{\tiny B\\C} (no label)

A\parbox[t]{3em}{\tiny\leavevmode\label{y}B\\C} (label before text)

A\parbox[t]{3em}{\tiny B\label{z}\\C} (label after text)
\end{document}
```

[image]